# Azure upload/install SSL certificate issue - "Can't upload certificate"

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

I followed these instructions to upload a server cert issued by Thawte: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg465712.aspx

So, I've got a PFX file and the cert complies with the requirements, that is:

```
- Contain a private key (well it's a PFX...).
- Purpose is Server Authentication.
- Subject name match the domain name that is used to access the service.
- Key size of 2048-bits.
```

For some reason when I upload it, it returns an error stating: "Can't upload certificate. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support".

**NB:**

```
- I can import that pfx to one of my local Windows machine with no problems.
- I've generated the CSR using certreq (can't see any problem with that)
- I included all certificates in the certificate path when I exported the PFX
```

If anyone can advise on how to resolve this issue it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you uploading the certificate through Portal?

Comment: Yes (sorry I should've mentioned that), I am uploading the cert through the management portal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted, I had to reduce the complexity of the password used for my private key (for reasons only god and Microsoft know)... Uploaded the PFX and no issues...